# How to use env variable on workflow level github-actions

Tags: github-actions

I have a simple workflow:

```
name: Test CI

env:
  path_to_watch_for_commits: 'testdir/testfile'

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
    paths:
      - ${{ env.path_to_watch_for_commits }}

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on:  ubuntu

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

I want to use variable `path_to_watch_for_commits` in paths. But this syntax is wrong. Also i try `${{ path_to_watch_for_commits }}` and `$path_to_watch_for_commits` with no results. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 10):

There is a [Naming conventions for environment variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environment-variables#naming-conventions-for-environment-variables) explaining that:

> Any new environment variables you set that point to a location on the filesystem should have a `_PATH` suffix. The `HOME` and `GITHUB_WORKSPACE` default variables are exceptions to this convention because the words "home" and "workspace" already imply a location.

Regarding the use of environment variables at different levels inside the workflow, here is an example with WORKFLOW, JOB and STEP variables:

```
name: Example

on: [push, workflow_dispatch]

env:
  WORKFLOW_VARIABLE: WORKFLOW

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      JOB_VARIABLE: JOB
    steps:
      - name: Run Commands with various variables
        if: ${{ env.WORKFLOW_VARIABLE == 'WORKFLOW' }}
        env:
          STEP_VARIABLE: STEP
        run: |
          echo "Hello World"
          echo "This is the $WORKFLOW_VARIABLE environment variable"
          echo "This is the $JOB_VARIABLE environment variable"
          echo "This is the $STEP_VARIABLE environment variable"
```

---

Regarding the possibility of the behaviour you want to achieve in your workflow, you can't set **variables at the workflow** and use them as paths on the same level, because:

> Variables are substituted in the runner operating system after the job
> is sent to the runner.

[Reference](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.0/actions/reference/environment-variables#about-environment-variables)

A workaround could be to trigger the workflow every time on `push` event, using the [paths-filter action](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter) with an if conditional to execute specific steps if it match your paths.

*It's not the best solution regarding optimisation, but it will work.*

Comment: I want to use variable in on -> push -> paths. Is it possible?

Comment: For what I looked for on the documentation and the community, it doesn't work (because _variables are substituted in the runner operating system after the job is sent to the runner_. [ref](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.0/actions/reference/environment-variables#about-environment-variables)). A workaround could be to trigger the workflow every time on push, using the [paths-filter action](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter) with an if conditional to execute specific steps if it match your paths. It's not the best solution regarding optimisation, but it'll work. I edited above